# Shortcut for checking if all $_POST fields are filled in php

Tags: php

I know that I can check if the superglobal $_POST is empty or not by using

```
empty / isset
```

However, I have many fields here. Is there any shortcut to check if all fields are filled? Instead of doing

```
if (!empty($_POST['a']) || !empty($_POST['b']) || !empty($_POST['c']) || !empty($_POST['d']).... ad nauseum)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) and compare both counts

```
if(count(array_filter($_POST))!=count($_POST)){
    echo "Something is empty";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response! It works like a charm! I will select this as the best answer when i am allowed to do so. Thanks a heap!

Comment: @erwinleonardy Your very welcome.  glad i helped.  :)

Answer (score 5):

You can loop through the $_POST variable.

For example:

```
$messages=array();
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
    if(empty($value))
        $messages[] = "Hey you forgot to fill this field: $key";
} 
print_r($messages);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I think the fastest and most efficient way of doing this is by using what roullie recommended. Since, in leau of checking one by one. It calculates the number of elements in an array.

Comment: @erwinleonardy I upvoted rouillie's answer and i like it too but don't say it is the most efficient way of doing that. Its just a speed trick to please our eyes that wow 2 lines of code and everything is done! Now what if someday you decide to tell user ***which fields*** are empty? If you have 20 fields on a form and you tell user hey something is empty; that doesn't help.

Comment: And this answer is far better when you get to that stage.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a function I just authored that might help.

if any of the arguments you pass is empty, it returns false. if not it'll return true.

```
function multi_empty() {
    foreach(func_get_args() as $value) {
        if (!isset($value) || empty($value)) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Example

```
multi_empty("hello","world",1234); //Returns true 
multi_empty("hello","world",'',1234); //Returns false
multi_empty("hello","world",1234,$notset,"test","any amount of arguments"); //Returns false
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `foreach()` loop to check each `$_POST` value:

```
foreach ($_POST as $val) {
    if(empty($val)) echo 'You have not filled up all the inputs';
}
```